# Autofac only works in controllers, not for referenced class libraries?

Tags: autofac, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have read the few articles there are on this and now got Autofac working with the Preview version of MVC6 and am injecting a service into my controller! Yaaay!

However I also added a injection in the service (which is a nuget class library) all registered in the StartUp.cs as per recommendation. And it just doesn't work!

It is exactly the same code as injecting the service into the controller, but not working, it injects the service as expected but the very next line which calls the injected repo in the service just gets an object reference error.

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "Autofac": "4.0.0-beta6-110",
    "Autofac.Framework.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-beta6-110",
    "Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "SceneStealer.Services.Interfaces": { },
    "SceneStealer.Models": { },
    "SceneStealer.Data": { },
    "SceneStealer.Data.Interfaces": { },
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019"
},
```

```cs
public class AutofacModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
                .Register(c => new ConferenceService())
                .As<IConferenceService>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.Register(c => new ConferenceRepo())
                .As<IConferenceRepo>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();


        }
    }
```

```cs
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add Application Insights data collection services to the services container.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddMvc();
            // Uncomment the following line to add Web API services which makes it easier to port Web API 2 controllers.
            // You will also need to add the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim package to the 'dependencies' section of project.json.
            // services.AddWebApiConventions();#services
            //Autofac config

            services.AddMvc();

            // Create the Autofac container builder.
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            // Add any Autofac modules or registrations.
            builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());
            // Populate the services.

            builder.Populate(services);
            // Build the container.
            var container = builder.Build();

            // Resolve and return the service provider.
            return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
        }
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: I don't understand... The question is about Autofac,therefore surely it should be in the title? otherwise it wouldn't make sense!

Comment: My comment was regarding the prefixing of title with *MVC6 -*, which I've removed ...

Comment: It would be good to post the full exception you're getting.

Comment: I literally am just gettiing an object reference not set to an instance of the object error on the class that should have been injected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I would try call builder.Populate before you call builder.RegisterModule

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair No, this is about DI, not a basic .NET null ref, if you read the question :)

Comment: Thanks @JoeAudette  I'll try that today..

Comment: Is your repo class public?

Comment: Yeap! And is referencing the Autofac and Autofac injection nuget packages

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I think it's related to modules, because I recently started using AutofacModules and now property injection isn't working.